# Assuming: $\forall x \in [0,1]:f(x) > x$ Prove: $\forall x \in [0,1]:f(x) > x + \varepsilon $

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ a continous function defined in the interval $[0,1]$.
Assuming: $\forall x \in [0,1]:f(x) > x$
Prove: $\forall x \in [0,1]:f(x) > x + \varepsilon $

I tried to use [Heine–Cantor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) and did some Algebra tricks but it didn't bring me to a safe shore :)

What do you suggest?
Thanks!

Comment: A continuous function on a compact interval attains its supremum and infimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $h:x\mapsto f(x)-x$ then $h$ is continuous on the compact $I=[0,1]$ hence $h$ is bounded (here we need to say bounded below) and reaches its minimum at $x_0\in I$ hence we have
$$h(x)\geq h(x_0)>0,\;\forall x\in I$$
Now take $\epsilon=\frac{h(x_0)}{2}$ and you have the result.

Comment: I have to say I had that in mind in a way, but couldn't phrase it mathematically. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Spot on, dear friend! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$, then for each $x\in [0,1]$, $g(x) > 0$, so for $\epsilon_x := g(x)/2$, there is a $\delta_x > 0$ such that
$$
y \in (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x) \Rightarrow g(y) > \epsilon_x
$$
Now $\{(x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x)\}$ is an open cover for $[0,1]$. Take a finite subcover, and let $\epsilon$ be the minimum of all the corresponding $\epsilon_x$'s.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with the term "finite subcover"