# Prove that there is an $\varepsilon$ such that $f(x) > x + \varepsilon$ for a continuous $f(x) > x$ at $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

**I know this question was answered by using another theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613900/assuming-forall-x-in-0-1fx-x-prove-forall-x-in-0-1fx-x) but I wish I could get comments on my way of trying to prove it.**

We were asked to prove that for a function $f(x) > x $ which is continuous in $[0,1]$ there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $f(x) > x + \epsilon$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

I tried a different method then suggested at the link above and would like to know if it's correct and if not what's wrong / missing.

I'll assume the opposite that $\forall \epsilon>0 , f(x) - x < \epsilon$. Also I know that $f(x) - x > 0$ from $f(x) > 0$ so I can deduce that $|f(x)-x| < \epsilon$ that would mean that for any $x \in [0,1]$  the limit of $f$ at that point is $x$, since $f$ is continuous I also know that the limit of $f$ at any $x \in [0,1]$ is $f(x)$ so $f(x)= x$ which is a contradiction to $f(x) > x$ hence there must be at least one $\epsilon$ for which $f(x) - x < \epsilon$

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean by "limit at that point", but you can rework your proof as follows : Suppose the theorem is not true, then for $\epsilon = 1/n, \exists x_n \in [0,1]$ such that
$$
|f(x_n) - x_n| < 1/n \qquad (\ast )
$$
Now $\{x_n\} \subset [0,1]$, which is compact, so there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to y \in [0,1]$, and from that and $(\ast )$, you can conclude that $f(y) = y$, which is a contradiction.

In any case, you need to appeal to the compactness of $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Well you do need to use the properties of continuous functions on a closed interval. And all the proofs of these properties require the completeness of real number system in a fundamental way. Some proofs above have used the compactness of the closed interval $[0, 1]$ which is again dependent on completeness of real numbers.

Another approach is to the use the following property of continuous functions: *if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then it is bounded on $[a, b]$ i.e. there exist constants $k, K$ such that $k \leq f(x) \leq K$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.* A proof can be easily found in any textbook of real analysis or on [my blog](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html).

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$ so that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and positive on $[0, 1]$. Then the function $h(x) = 1/g(x)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and hence is bounded on $[0, 1]$. Now let's assume that there is no positive $\epsilon$ which leads to $f(x) > x + \epsilon$ or $g(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. This means that for any arbitrarily chosen positive number $\epsilon$ we have at least one $x_{\epsilon} \in [0, 1]$ such that $g(x_{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon$. Then $h(x_{\epsilon}) \geq 1/\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and $1/\epsilon \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, it follows that $h(x)$ is unbounded on $[0, 1]$. This contradiction proves that our assumption is wrong and there exists at least one positive number $\epsilon$ such that $g(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting a proof by contradiction, but you're not making your assumptions precise. What do you mean when you say "I'll assume the opposite that $\forall \epsilon>0 , f(x) - x < \epsilon$."?

You didn't specify, what $x$ refers to. Do you mean $\forall \epsilon \forall x \dots$? Or $\forall \epsilon \exists x \dots$? The latter is the correct negation of the hypothesis, but you seem to be working with the first one.

Comment: Oh my bad. Then taking the correct form I assume that $\forall \epsilon \exists x_0$ such that... (what I wrote in my post). Now if I take some that $x_0 \in [0,1]$ and try to show by the definition of the limit that for $|x-x_0|<\delta \to |f(x_0) - x_0| < \epsilon$ since that's I assumed, now as I wrote earlier from continuity I know that the limit of the function at $x_0$ is $f(x_0)$ and also from the last paragraph I know it's $x_0$ hence a contradiction to $f(x)>x$. Is that ok?

Comment: @byentropy: No. Write out the full definition for the limit to see that what you are doing is essentially moving the existential quantifier outside the universal quantifier, which is not allowed. In this case the compactness of $[0,1]$ is crucial. Even $[0,1)$ won't work, and you should find a counterexample for that.

Comment: @user21820, sorry I am still not getting why it isn't correct. If I go by $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta,0<|x-a| < \delta => |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and here I can control $|f(x)-x|$ by assuming first that it is smaller than any epsilon. Thus it shows for every delta that it is true (although I need to show there exists at least one delta I can show it is true for every delta). Why isn't that going by the definition of the limit?

Comment: @byentropy: I wrote a detailed answer but lost it. To analyze what went wrong with your argument by yourself, follow it step by step on the counter-example for $[0,1)$ and see where it breaks down. Basically, do not ever pull a variable outside its scope. You have $x$ in a $\forall \epsilon$ scope and you pulled it out. It depended on $\epsilon$, and you cannot remove that dependency.